# MySQL: Select distinct values from one column if other column has two determined values in junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, junction-table

I have junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE `book_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

with values like

```
INSERT INTO `book_tags` (`id`, `book_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(3, 20, 1),
(4, 20, 2),
(5, 21, 1),
(6, 22, 2),
(7, 24, 2);
```

How can I find the books (book_id) which have **two or more determined tags** at the same time?
For example, how can I find a book which have tag_id=2 **AND** tag_id=1

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**UPDATED**:

Looking through stackoverflow I've found the answer on my question.

For 2 required tags the solution will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `book_tags`
WHERE `tag_id` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY book_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This solution is suitable for my particular case, since I know that in my table there is no rows with the same pair of values of book_id and tag_id.

Thank you @Barbaros Özhan and @scaisEdge for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a subquery for tag_id  in you searched set and the check for count distinct  tag_id quae to the number of your searched tag

Assuming tag 1, 2 then

```
select book_id 
from (
  select book_id, tag_id 
  from  book_tags 
  where tag_id in  (1,2)
) t 
group by book_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2  


select book_id 
from (
  select book_id, tag_id 
  from  book_tags 
  where tag_id in  (1,2,5,7, 9, 11)
) t 
group by book_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 5
```

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge! It's a good idea!
 But If there will be 5 or more required tags, which book should have?

Comment: @oshka  the query conceptually remains the same  .. just change the IN clause with the proper value  and the Having constraints with the number of tag required ..  (in the sample you provided  5 tags  return no books)

Comment: @oshka Note that we're still using IN() here

Comment: anyway answer  updated  with  a sample for 5 tag  with id  (1,2,5,7, 9, 11)

Answer (score 1):

It would be an elastic option using a `having` clause as in the following way as you add after `in` operator's list(`in (1,2,3,...)`) more `tag_id` to filter:

```
select `book_id` 
  from `book_tags` 
 where `tag_id` in (1,2,3) 
 group by `book_id` 
having count(`tag_id`) = count(distinct `tag_id`)
   and count(distinct `tag_id`) > count(distinct `book_id`);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=45022b4e4b7e2e7bf96972559b84ba16)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT book_id FROM books_tags WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2`?

Or

`SELECT book_id FROM books_tags WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2)`

Comment: Thank you @Mido! Bot I need to find all book which have both  tag_id=2 AND tag_id=1

Comment: @oshka the above query would find the book_ids 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 as each one of those has tag_id 1 or tag_id 2. You might be confusing my usage of _and_ and _or_. Saying that tag_id = 1 OR 2 would mean "get all the values that have tag_id = 1 and also get all the values that have tag_id = 2". Isn't this what you're trying to accomplish?